# Java: Using arrays so make a short number to word code

Tags: java, numbers

So far, this is my code 
its an assignment to create a number to word code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Enter a number from 1 - 999");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

    String[]hundreds = {"","One hundred","Two hundred","Three hundred", "Four hundred", "Five hundred", "Six hundred","Seven hundred","Eight hundred","Nine hundred"};
    String[]tens = {"","ten", "tewnty", "thirty","fourty" , "fifty", "sixty", "seventy","eighty", "ninety" }; 
    String[] ones = {"", "one", "two" , "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "eleven"};    

    int H=number/100;
    int remainder= number %100;
    System.out.print(hundreds[H]);         
    int I= remainder / 10;
    int remainder1 = remainder % 10;
    int J = remainder1 / 1;
    int remainder2= remainder%1;

    if (remainder1 <=11 || remainder1 >=19){
        System.out.print(teens[J]);
    }
    else{
        System.out.print(tens[I]);
        System.out.print(ones[J]);
    }
}
}
```

Okay, original problem fixed, where it wouldn't show up, but 561 shows up as five hundred eleven, which part is the error and how can I fix it, and what was wrong

Comment: apart from the answer, I am curious to know how do you plan to print eleven, twelve...? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit complicated.
Here is how you can tackle it

```
    int H = number/100;//hundreds digit
    System.out.print(hundred[H]);

    int remainder = number % 100;//the tens and ones digits
    int I = remainder/10;//tens digit
    int remainder1 = remainder % 10;//ones digit

    if(remainder >= 11 && remainder <=19)
    System.out.print(teens[remainder1]);//remainder1 - 1 considering the array starts from 11
    else
    {
        System.out.print(tens[I]);
        System.out.print(ones[remainder1]);
    }
```

here, `teens[]` is your array for the numbers from 11 to 19. the others are just the same. Also dont include eleven in your `ones[]` array

Comment: Was the eleven in the ones array the one affecting the 561 > Five hundred eleven? 
511 worked, so was it having trouble with the ones?

Comment: Possible. But I didn't understand your code so I wrote my own.

Comment: I hope this works. It's of course easier to have a separate array for eleven to nineteen.

Comment: It worked, thank you, going to try and find the issue and then post and compare. 
Bonus : removing the eleven from the ones array didnt happen to work, must've been something else

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
    int H=number/100;
    int remainder= number %100;     // you want number here
    System.out.println(hundreds[H]);
    System.out.println();

    int I= remainder / 10;
    int remainder1 = remainder % 10;  // you want remainder here
    System.out.println(tens[I]);
    System.out.println();

    int J = remainder1 / 1;
    int remainder2= remainder1 %1;  // you want remainder1  here
    System.out.println(ones[J]);
```

Also change tewnty -> twenty